# Локальная база данных в веб приложении

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование

Подскажите такой момент. Стоит задача разработки веб-приложения для корпоративной сети. Далеко не все клиенты имеют быстрое соединение с интернетом. Хотелось бы иметь локальную базу данных - справочников, откуда бы подгружались данные в приложение.Как поступить - ставить Php+mysql на каждого клиента например? Или есть какие-то более изящные решения. Насколько такое решение правильное в плане производительности? В сети есть старое железо и софт должен работать и на нем.
 Сами справочники обновляться будут редко. И как обновление их проводить - что-то типа репликации основной базы справочников?

Comment: Если у вас web приложение то причем тут php на клиенте. он же без web-сервера с браузером работать не будет. И в современных браузерах есть несколько видов хранилищ, в том числе и SQL-хранилища. Работа с ними происходит прямо в браузере с помощью javascript

Comment: имелось ввиду поставить локальный php-интерпретатор и локальную субд mysql и ajax запросы соответственно отправлять на localhost при обращении к справочникам. Могут ли браузеры иметь доступ к локальным файлам через JS - насколько знаю нет такой возможности?

Comment: Зачем доступ к локальным файлам, если в браузерах есть встроенные SQL-сервера (обычно sqlite). Да и большинство справочников фактически ключ-значение (значение может быть json объектом). А уж для таких вещей обычных localStorage подойдет.

Comment: Вот тут не совсем понятно как наполнять данными эти справочники. При заходе на сервер он будет подгружать данные, сохранять их в браузерную sqlite и потом брать из нее данные? Если с локальной связкой php+mysql понятно - через Mysqldump наполняем данными нашу локальную базу и потом обращаемся к ней.

Comment: @Артем Тихонович моменты синхронизации - это вам виднее по логике приложения. Смысл такой: если таблица A пустая, стягиваем таблицу A . А дальше - клиент должен каким-то образом узнавать, что надо сбросить у себя данные таблицы A, если данные в таблице A изменились. Каким способом - зависит от задачи, от логики.

Comment: смотря для чего они используются. Если по ID получить объект и какую то инфу из него показать, то ищем объект в localStorage (он все таки часто удобнее, чем SQL для таких простых задач), если его нет - запрашиваем сервер и пишем в хранилище. Если же нужен полный перечень что бы какую нибудь меню/выпадающий список показать, то грузим целиком с сервера и например запоминаем номер версии справочника. И при работе с сервером этот номер сверяем периодически, что бы обновить вовремя

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу по задаче - если главный интерес, это минимизировать трафик: гораздо полезнее бекенд(PHP или там Java, С#) - сделать json-сервервом. Плюс к этому сервер может раздавать статику nginx-ом, которую клиент незамедлительно кешиует и регулирует момент, когда кеш сбросить нужно. Разумеется у веб-приложения будет в таком случае [толстый клиент](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) , который можно реализовать на js-фреймворке, вроде angular.

Главное в таком случае - правильно организовать кеширование на клиенте, чтобы единожды загруженный контент повторно не загружался: благо сегодня средств для этого много. Например - те-же справочники, подгрузили, положили в localStorage, и дальше берём их только из localStorage. Это соответствует паттерну [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) ,  но могут возникнуть проблемы с вопросом - когда кеш сбрасывать: для этого надо посылать сигнал клиенту, например через постоянное websocket соединение с сервером.

А локальный sql в качестве дубликата основной БД - не советовал бы, намучаться с ним можно порядком, т.к. синхронизация БД - всегда одна из самых сложных операций. Хотя [что-то есть на эту тему](http://sqlite-sync.com/)